# Receive music over bluetooth in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluetooth

I have a raspberry pi that I want to set up like a BlueTooth speaker.

I want to connect to the raspberry pi using my phone, play music, and receive it on the raspberry pi's side, where the audio is sent to the speaker.

Is this possible using node.js? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. There's a library called `node-bluetooth` that should do what you're looking for. You can check it out [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bluetooth)